# Key points for unofficial stats-101 for service guys?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, teaching, careers

**Background:**

In my previous job there was an official "stats 101" course.  It was brilliant.  It gave all the production and engineering folks a shared vocabulary, and provided a decent foundation to patch the big holes in understanding.

My current job has no such infra structure but in my personal opinion there is good value to be returned by making unofficial training on the topic.  As convenient as "covering what the other company covered" is appealing, it is not the same environment.  The previous company was about high-volume production while the current is more service-as-product and software-as-service.  They are going to have different needs.

**Question:**

What are the 101-topics that are going to be high value in a service-as-product environment that aren't going to be the same as fabrication of products?  Can you suggest topics, content, or even texts and references?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it should be just about the same stuff, with different examples. Control charts, fishbone diagrams, other Ishikawa tools as a foundation. A bit on principles of confidence intervals, simple regression, simple designs. Service quality is really no different from product quality, though it can be hard to get people to agree on what outcomes to measure. So you need to do more work (perhaps with the help of fishbone diagrams) to define what is the size and shape of quality service and what measures get at it.